# JSF form data and validation issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In JSF form we have multiple input fields like text and upload file etc. Whenever i submit the form if there is any validation error occurs that point time i am loosing the form data like uploaded file etc.

How to retrieve or persist form data while validation error time in JSF form?

Comment: Have you tried to include `proccess="@form"` in the submit button?

Comment: Yes i have tried with process attribute. Is there any specific attribute in upload tag?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: please include relevant snippets from your code to aid in determining the problem. thanks